# How do servers behave when browsers request embedded resources that do not exist?

Tags: http, browser, http-status-code-404

Let's take the following hypothetical situation:

- an HTTP server has a custom error page set up `/404.html` and does a server-side forward for any URL that gives a 404 response (for example `/blabla.html`) to the `404.html` page
- a browser requests an existing page from the server, say `/home.html`
- the page contains `<img src="a.jpg" alt="a" />`, but that resource does not exist on the server
- the browser receives a 404 for the resource, marks it as missing and does **not** receive any response (tested this in Chrome and FF in the network tab of the dev console - the response bit is empty)

My question is: what happens on the server when the image is requested?

My guess is the browser cuts off the connection when it gets the 404 status in the header so it doesn't wait or download the response. My other guess is that it's implementation specific, but I'm curious if the servers notice that the connection has been cut off.

Answer (score 0):

The browser will get your error page but he can't handle html in an image. (It will throw an error in the console)
If you would do it with a frame it will show your error page.

Comment: This is not true - neither Chrome nor FF show any error besides the not found. I assume the response body is _not_ downloaded and I want to know whether the server stops processing or not. See this: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/72/console404.jpg/